# Set Azure DevOps variable with powershell as int instead of string

Tags: arrays, azure, powershell, azure-devops, devops

I am a bit stuck on my release pipeline.
It is a pretty basic pipeline:

Stage1 (build JSON)

- task 1: SET VARS
- task 2: create ARM template

Stage2 is deploy ARM template

Task 1 is an inline powershell script which looks like:

```
$content = Get-Content $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_SFTP\SFTP-Deploy\parameters.csv
$array = $content.split(",")

$sftpUserCount = $array.Count
$SFTPUsers = $content
$userNames = $array | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sftpUserCount;]$sftpUserCount"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SFTPUsers;]$SFTPUsers"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=userNames;]$userNames"
```

So it reads from an CSV and sets the 3 variables (one counter, one array and one JSON array). All of that seems to be well.

My template expects for the "sftpUserCount" an integer (type: int), for $usernames and $sftpusers an array.
But it is interpreting all of the variables as string. Which results into the following error in stage 2:

```
##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'Template parameter JToken type is not valid. Expected 'Integer'. Actual 'String'. Please see https://aka.ms/resource-manager-parameter-files for usage details.'.
```

If I set the variables directly into the pipeline it is working correctly. So is there a way to fill the variables in it's correct type (string, array, int) ?

Comment: Did you try to set Powershell variable type to Integer?
[int]$sftpUserCount = $array.Count

Comment: @AndriyBilous: I did. Still the same error. If I run the PowerShell script locally and test it with:

`$sftpusercount -is [int]`
the result is "true". So PowerShell is interpreting it as an integer. But if the pipeline variable is being set with the value. It seems that it is a string.

Comment: Could you please update question with code were you use your custom variables?

Comment: It seems that it is working now! It is possible to use the variables within the same stage. But somehow, the variables are not working in the upcoming stage(s).

Comment: Variables set from a script are job-scoped - they won't work in different stages or jobs. To use a variable between stages, you need [output variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-stage).